# Could not autowire. No beans of 'NoteRepository' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Controller class is below.

```
@Controller
public class app {

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String hello() {
        return "Hello app";
    }
}
```

It **works fine** when I navigate through url. But when this below code is added it says `"Could not autowire. No beans of 'NoteRepository' type found"`.

```
@Autowired
    NoteRepository noteRepository;

    // Create a new Note
    @PostMapping("/notes")
    public Note createNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note) {
        return noteRepository.save(note);
    }
```

App controller class is in the ***same package*** where main class(which run the application) is. but when we add above code to a controller in different package it **doesn't show error**. but it doesn't work when we navigate through url even a simple get method.

My main class is below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class CrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Repository class is

```
@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, Long> {
}
```

My project structure

[image: Image 1]

I want to find solution to:

1. Inject an instance of `NoteRepository`. I always get the message "Could not autowire. No beans of  type found" error. Spring cannot inject it, doesn't matter if the interface is in the same or a different package.
2. I am not able to run methods in a controller(`MyController`) that are located in a different package than application entry point.

[image]

Comment: Done. check the updated one.

Comment: Your code seems fine. The repo class is probably not being component scanned.

Comment: try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your configuration class

Comment: Move your `CrudApplication` to `com.demo` and not a sub package that way it will scan all packages and automatically detect the repositories and entities.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are correct. I should have create model, controller packages inside the CRUD(main) package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main symptom is this:

> App controller class is in the same package where main class(which run the application) is. but when we add above code to a controller in different package it doesn't show error. but it doesn't work when we navigate through url even a simple get method.

By default, Spring Boot application will only auto discover beans declared in the same package than the main class. For beans that are in a different package, you need to specify to include them. You can use [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) for this.

```
package foo.bar.main;

//import statements....

//this annotation will tell Spring to search for bean definitions
//in "foo.bar" package and subpackages.
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class CrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}



package foo.bar.controller;

//import statements....

//since @ComponentScan, now this bean will be discovered
@Controller
public class app {

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String hello() {
        return "Hello app";
    }
}
```

For Spring Data to recognize which repositories should create, you should add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to your main class. Also, in order for Spring Data and the JPA implementation to scan the                                      entities, add `@EntityScan`:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.repository.packagename")
@EntityScan("your.domain.packagename")
public class CrudApplication {
    //code...
}
```

Comment: Both classes you have mentioned here is in the same package and when we navigate through url it prnts "Hello app". Problem begins when i try to add instance of repository class which is in another package called repository.

Comment: You mention that if you move the controller to a different package then you cannot get results when hitting the url. That means that the bean for the controller wasn’t created. With that in mind, you need to tell Spring where the beans can be found. Spring doesn’t do any magic.

Comment: It doesn't wort when i move to different package but is doesn't show error  "Could not autowire ". when in the same package it shows. check the project structure.

Comment: That’s because Spring is not trying to create a bean of that class. I suggest you to review the basics of Spring.

Comment: Repository class in different package but when i tried @ComponentScan it doesn't work for note repository instance.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. It will discover all the beans in the package and its sub packages. Placing the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a top-level class will solve the problem (and is the recommended approach).

Comment: please check highlighted points in the question. What i want do is solve the problem with Note repository instance. Intellij raise compile time error that "Could not autowired"

Comment: I could able to solve question 2 with @Luiggi 's answer but autowire problem is still remaining.

Comment: @LahiruGamage answer updated. Also, wording is important. I edited your question for better understanding of the issues.

Comment: I have solved it using other question from stack. Anyway what you have added is the code which solved my error. It will be important for someone in future. Thank you for your help  @Luiggi

Answer (score 0):

you should add packages for spring to scan them

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"package1", "package2"})
```